# Add a note using the OOB dialog from a webresource

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

Im working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The client is requesting to be able to add notes from a webresources.

I thought that something like this will do the trick:

```
 Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("annotation", null, parameters);
```

or even the classic

```
 /main.aspx?etn=annotation&pagetype=entityrecord#
```

But I receive a "Query Builder Error: The specified record type does not exist in Microsoft Dynamics CRM"

It seems like notes is not something we can open in that way but I cannot found the right way (if even exists!)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone in the future: This will open a dialog with the Regarding field filled, the textboxs for title and description and the attachments field.

```
  function createNote() {
        var EntityID = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(); // to get entity id
        var ServicerURL = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl(); // to get server url
        var etc =Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters().etc; // to get entity type code, make sure not to hard code it, because it could changed in another deployment
        var NotesURL = ServicerURL + "/notes/edit.aspx?pId=" + EntityID + "&pType=" + etc;
        var features = "copyhistory=no,top=110,left=280,width=600,height=400";
        window.open(NotesURL, "", features);
    }
```